# Warning: encountered two children with the same key, is appearing as an error in my REACT app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm in the process of building out a simple react act that display REST data from my localhost URL.

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure why, at first I thought it was the data within the API itself but I think that's not the case for this?

I am not getting any `npm start` errors, the error appears when I inspect a page with browser tools.

Here is the full error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
    at div
    at Grid (http://localhost:4000/static/js/0.chunk.js:1556:35)
    at WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (http://localhost:4000/static/js/0.chunk.js:6385:31)
    at main
    at Container (http://localhost:4000/static/js/0.chunk.js:1101:23)
    at WithStyles(ForwardRef(Container)) (http://localhost:4000/static/js/0.chunk.js:6385:31)
    at UserBuckets (http://localhost:4000/static/js/main.chunk.js:363:5)
    at LoadingComponent (http://localhost:4000/static/js/main.chunk.js:999:5)
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:4000/static/js/main.chunk.js:173:89)
    at Route (http://localhost:4000/static/js/0.chunk.js:48473:29)
    at Switch (http://localhost:4000/static/js/0.chunk.js:48675:29)
    at Router (http://localhost:4000/static/js/0.chunk.js:48108:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:4000/static/js/0.chunk.js:47728:35)
```

Could someone point out what is causing this error in my code? I haven't been able to solve it myself.

Here is my required code:

`App.js`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserBuckets from './components/BucketLists';
import LoadingComponent from './components/Loading';


function App() {
    const ListLoading = LoadingComponent(UserBuckets);
    const [appState, setAppState] = useState({
        loading: false,
        buckets: null,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setAppState({ loading: true });
        const apiUrl = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/`;
        fetch(apiUrl)
            .then((data) => data.json())
            .then((buckets) => {
                setAppState({ loading: false, buckets: buckets });
            });
    }, [setAppState]);
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Latest Buckets</h1>
            <ListLoading isLoading={appState.loading} buckets={appState.buckets} />
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

`bucketList.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    cardMedia: {
        paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
    },
    link: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1, 1.5),
    },
    cardHeader: {
        backgroundColor:
            theme.palette.type === 'light'
                ? theme.palette.grey[200]
                : theme.palette.grey[700],
    },
    bucketTitle: {
        fontSize: '16px',
        textAlign: 'left',
    },
    bucketText: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'left',
        alignItems: 'baseline',
        fontSize: '12px',
        textAlign: 'left',
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}));

const UserBuckets = (props) => {
    const { buckets } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();
    if (!buckets || buckets.length === 0) return <p>Can not find any buckets, sorry</p>;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Container maxWidth="md" component="main">
                <Grid container spacing={5} alignItems="flex-end">
                    {buckets.map((buckets) => {
                        return (
                            // Enterprise card is full width at sm breakpoint
                            <Grid item key={buckets.owner} xs={12} md={4}>
                                <Card className={classes.card}>
                                    <CardMedia
                                        className={classes.cardMedia}
                                        image="https://source.unsplash.com/random"
                                        title="Image title"
                                    />
                                    <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                                        <Typography
                                            gutterBottom
                                            variant="h6"
                                            component="h2"
                                            className={classes.bucketTitle}
                                        >
                                            {buckets.name.substr(0, 50)}...
                                        </Typography>
                                        <div className={classes.bucketText}>
                                            <Typography
                                                component="p"
                                                color="textPrimary"
                                            ></Typography>
                                            <Typography variant="p" color="textSecondary">
                                                {buckets.stock_list}...
                                            </Typography>
                                        </div>
                                    </CardContent>
                                </Card>
                            </Grid>
                        );
                    })}
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
export default UserBuckets;
```

`Loading.js`

```
import React from 'react';

function LoadingComponent(Component) {
    return function LoadingComponent({ isLoading, ...props }) {
        if (!isLoading) return <Component {...props} />;
        return (
            <p style={{ fontSize: '25px' }}>
                We are waiting for the data to load!...
            </p>
        );
    };
}

export default LoadingComponent;
```

Thank in advance...

Comment: Sounds like an owner can have multiple buckets? Choose a different key, then?

Comment: The only `key` in the code in your question is `buckets.owner`. Can a user own more than one bucket? Maybe you can use a truly unique identifier for the `key`, e.g. if a bucket has an `id`.

Comment: Is the owner unique for every bucket? If not, then don't use it as a key

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, yes that was the simple issue that needed fixing, I have solved the problem by using `id` as the `item key`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error came from this culprit and my mistake not seeing the important of the letter `key` in `item key`. This is how I solved my error:

original code
`<Grid item key={buckets.owner} xs={12} md={4}>`

fixed code
`<Grid item key={buckets.id} xs={12} md={4}>`